# Filter array of urls containing a whitelisted substring and not containing any blacklisted substrings

Tags: php, arrays, regex, filtering, preg-grep

I have an array shown below

```
[
    'http://api.tweetmeme.com/imagebutton.gif?url=http://mashable.com/2010/09/25/trailmeme/', 
    'http://cdn.mashable.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-digg-this/i/gbuzz-feed.png',
    'http://mashable.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-digg-this/i/fb.jpg',
    'http://mashable.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-digg-this/i/diggme.png',
    'http://ec.mashable.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/bizspark2.gif',
    'http://cdn.mashable.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/web.png',
    'http://mashable.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Screen-shot-2010-09-24-at-10.51.26-PM.png', 
    'http://cdn.mashable.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/bizspark.jpg',
    'http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/lxx00QTjYBaYojpnpnTa6MXUmh4/0/di',
    '',
    'http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~at/lxx00QTjYBaYojpnpnTa6MXUmh4/1/di',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?i=0N_mvMwPHYk:j5Pmi_N-JQ8:D7DqB2pKExk',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?i=0N_mvMwPHYk:j5Pmi_N-JQ8:V_sGLiPBpWU',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?i=0N_mvMwPHYk:j5Pmi_N-JQ8:F7zBnMyn0Lo',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?d=qj6IDK7rITs',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?d=_e0tkf89iUM',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?i=0N_mvMwPHYk:j5Pmi_N-JQ8:gIN9vFwOqvQ',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?d=yIl2AUoC8zA',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?d=P0ZAIrC63Ok',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?d=I9og5sOYxJI',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?d=CC-BsrAYo0A',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/Mashable?i=0N_mvMwPHYk:j5Pmi_N-JQ8:_cyp7NeR2Rw',
    '',
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/Mashable/~4/0N_mvMwPHYk',
]
```

I want to:

1. remove every empty array element,
2. remove every array item without
   extensions `.jpg`, `.png`, or `.gif` in its name,
3. and remove array items containing keywords such as `digg`, `fb`, `tweet`, `bizspark`.

I would like it to retain:

```
5 => http://cdn.mashable.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/web.png 
6 => http://mashable.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Screen-shot-2010-09-24-at-10.51.26-PM.png
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: i have no idea about using regular expressions... so cant go any further. all i can probably do at this moment is remove empty array elements

Comment: You do not need regular expressions. Be creative with [stristr](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) and comparison functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using, e.g., [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will give you flexibility and ease of maintenance (changing requirements, de-bugging, etc.):

```
function url_array_filter($url)
{
    static $words = array('digg', 'fb', 'tweet', 'bizspark');
    static $extens = array('.jpg', '.png', '.gif');
    $ret = true;
    if (!$url) {
        $ret = false;
    } elseif (str_replace($words, '', $url) != $url) {
        $ret = false;
    } else {
        $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
        if (in_array(substr($path, -4), $extens)) {
            $ret = false;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

$arr = array_filter($arr, 'url_array_filter');
print_r($arr);
```

(Works for the array given, but may need changes; it's demo code.)

Comment: Changing substr($path, -4) to strrchr($path, '.') will get rid of the integer constant.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (
        empty($value)||
        (preg_match('#^http:\/\/(.*)\.(gif|png|jpg)$#i', $value) == 0)||
        (preg_match('#(tweet|bizspark)#i', $value) > 0)
    ) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The required business logic can be baked into a single regex pattern.

Starting from the front of the input string, traverse one character at a time and disqualify the entire string if a blacklisted substring is encountered. Then only qualify strings with the whitelisted file type.  I am using `[^?]` instead of `.` to enforce that the conditions are meet prior to the possible querystring segment of the url.

By consequence, any url string which contains one of the whitelisted file types will be a non-empty string.

If further tightening of the validation is required, better rules must be explained by the asker and a more challenging set of input string supplied.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vseDp))

```
var_export(
    preg_grep(
        '/^(?:(?:digg|fb|tweet|bizspark)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^?])+\.(?:gif|jpg|png)/i',
         $array
    )
);
```